# JSoup doesn't work with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I noticed one interesting thing with my app ( I use Jsoup inside AsyncTask)

After that my app crashed.
LogCat is:

```
 12-15 11:16:43.023: I/dalvikvm(371): Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.example.myexample.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground
12-15 11:16:43.033: W/dalvikvm(371): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3462: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;.connect (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection;
12-15 11:16:43.033: D/dalvikvm(371): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
12-15 11:16:43.033: D/dalvikvm(371): VFY: dead code 0x0006-000d in Lcom/example/myexample/MainActivity$MyTask;.doInBackground ([Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
12-15 11:16:43.113: W/dalvikvm(371): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-15 11:16:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(371):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Fatal exception connected with Async! But I don't understand why
My App:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MyTask mt;
  TextView tvInfo;
  String URL="http://en.wikipedia.org/";
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
  }

  public void onclick(View v) {
    mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute(URL);
  }

  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      Document doc;
      String title=null;
      String what1=null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      tvInfo.setText("Please wait...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      // TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
       String url=params[0];
       Document doc;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        String what1=doc.title();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


      return what1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      tvInfo.setText(result);
    }
  }
}
```

If I change my code (without JSoup) Async works good:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MyTask mt;
  TextView tvInfo;
  String URL="http://en.wikipedia.org/";
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
  }

  public void onclick(View v) {
    mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute(URL);
  }

  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      Document doc;
      String title=null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      tvInfo.setText("Please wait");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      // TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
       String url=params[0];
       //doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
       //String title = doc.title();
      // Log.d("AsyncTask doInBackground","URL: " + params[0]);
      return url;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      tvInfo.setText(result);
    }
  }
}
```

In TextView I get a Url of Wiki. 
Please, can anyone help me with this fact.
Thank you!

P.S I add permission of internet in Manifest file
P.P.S I use JSoup version 1.7.1 (added as external jar file)

Comment: You are getting error **Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect** , is the library included in the build?

Comment: Specifically, is the JSoup JAR in `libs/`?

Comment: Yes, I Include it. I did so right click on project->build path-> add external archives.
Interest,that LogCat is underline it as green and continue to run my app. Exception starts only with Async

Comment: @CommonsWare please decribe me, how to add in libs? Where can I find libs/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I did so right click on project->build path-> add external archives

Please undo that, then create a `libs/` directory in your project (as a peer of `src/`, `res/`, etc.) if you do not already have one. Then, put the JSoup JAR in the `libs/` directory. This will both add it to your build path *and* include its contents in your APK file.