# Debugger Will Not Reach Breakpoint - Throws Exception Instead

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I'm setting a breakpoint at the line:

```
   doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
```

but for some reason when I attempt to step over starting at this line it skips to the line

```
} catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

and throws an exception (therefore never getting a value for title) and I'm not sure why.

Any suggestions?

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    String url = "http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=ABBOTT&fname=LAUREA";
    String tr;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                for (Element row : tableRows) {
                    Elements cells = row.select("td");
                    if (cells.size() > 0) {
                        title = cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(3).text();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
10-07 15:42:21.591: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7981): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
10-07 15:42:21.611: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5cbaa000 size:122880 offset:0 fd:60
10-07 15:42:21.611: E/(7981): Can't open file for reading
10-07 15:42:21.611: E/(7981): Can't open file for reading
10-07 15:42:21.621: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7981): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
10-07 15:42:21.641: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ccd6000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:64
10-07 15:42:21.681: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5cf02000 size:122880 offset:0 fd:67
10-07 15:42:21.721: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d166000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:70
10-07 15:42:21.771: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d2fc000 size:122880 offset:0 fd:74
10-07 15:42:22.091: W/System.err(7981): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "sheriff.org": No address associated with hostname
10-07 15:42:22.281: W/System.err(7981):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:463)
10-07 15:42:22.281: W/System.err(7981):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:279)
10-07 15:42:22.281: W/System.err(7981):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:253)
10-07 15:42:22.281: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
10-07 15:42:22.281: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-07 15:42:22.281: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
10-07 15:42:22.281: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:46)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-07 15:42:22.291: W/System.err(7981):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:448)
10-07 15:42:22.301: W/System.err(7981):     ... 25 more
10-07 15:42:22.311: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5cbaa000 size:122880
10-07 15:42:22.311: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5cf02000 size:122880
10-07 15:42:22.311: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d2fc000 size:122880
10-07 15:42:22.311: D/memalloc(7981): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca92000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:54
```

Comment: :S .. thats because there is an exception

Comment: Any idea how this can be corrected?

Comment: Move the breakpoint to an earlier line.

Comment: Your statement `doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();` consists of two major operations: `Jsoup.connect(params[0])` and `get()`. I suspect that the first operation throws an exception

Comment: try this link may be you find your solution
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895211/jsoup-doesnt-work-with-asynctask

Comment: The logcat clearly shows your problem: `Unable to resolve host "sheriff.org": No address associated with hostname`. Try adding `http://` to your URL.

Comment: @Tanis.7x The url has `http://` ... But yes, the host resolve is failing. YOu could try adding `www.` but clutching straws.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the internet permission in my manifest which prevented the URL from being reached.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable answer to me.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I concur : )